# Code Hinting with CSS in Dreamweaver 5.5

Tags: css, dreamweaver, code-hinting

I am currently using the trial version of Dreamweaver 5.5 to be able to - hopefully - get a better understanding of the benefits of this program. I had previously used Aptana Studio 3 for a couple days and may have come to the conclusion that it is better than Dreamweaver at actual HTML/CSS **coding**.

My problem, or advice I need, is that I'm currently following some Lynda training videos on CSS and the exercise files have the CSS embedded directly into the HTML page using the `<stlye>` tags. In Aptana I was having difficulties trying to get "code assist" with classes/ids, but now in Dreamweaver I don't even know if that option is available. When writing simple CSS rules nothing is showing up (granted I do not have any windows open beside the main coding window). Is there a way to get some sort of code hinting when typing a `.` or `#` or even after the colon in something similar to `span:`?

*As an optional side question, what HTML/CSS editor would you recommend that would benefit the "coder" over the "visual designer"?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see code hinting for CSS rules and HTML, not classes and ID's that you have specified. Once you start writing the CSS you will see the code hinting.

so writing

```
#myDiv
```

will not give you any hints. this will give you hint:

```
{
```

It will give you a list of selectors. Now when you start to write the rule:

```
Background-color:
```

You will get your specific code hinting right away when you type the first letter.

Comment: I'm currently writing the CSS and I'm not seeing any code hinting. I have the HTML already written. I am a little confused by your answer.

Comment: Yes now I understand what you mean by actually writing the rules. I was just hoping that with a powerful tool like Dreamweaver it would be able to help me with classes/ids/etc. I find it a little discouraging that it doesn't give advice when I type the letter 'h' and give me the options: h1, h2, etc. In Aptana it does but for some reason my default setup isn't giving advice when I type `.` or `#` like it should. That is why I made the switch to the trial Dreamweaver.

Comment: yeah I pretty sure DW doesn't hint for this, since "." and "#" are usually values that you specify in your HTML.

Comment: This is getting off topic of what I initially asked but you don't use `. #` in the HTML do you? That is how you select class and ids in the CSS right? -- I'm just following these CSS tutorials.

Comment: yes of course. When I say that it is specified I mean that you write your id's and classes in your HTML and use . and # in your CSS to communicate with those.